# how to add image filters using fabric.js

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I would like to be able to add image filters to an image that the user uploads locally. The local upload works fine but the image is not converted to grayscale. Here is my code:

```
$("#file_input").change(function (e) {

    var URL = window.webkitURL || window.URL;
    var url = URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]);
    img = new Image();      
    img.src = url;
    img.onload = function () {
        ctx = document.getElementById('myCanvas').getContext("2d");

    ///
     fabric.Image.fromURL( img.src, function( img ) {

  // add filter
  img.filters.push(new fabric.Image.filters.Grayscale());

  // apply filters and re-render canvas when done
  img.applyFilters(ctx.renderAll.bind(ctx));

  // add image onto canvas
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, myCanvas.width, myCanvas.height);
});
    }

    ///
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

i don't understand your code.but i think you want something like this..

```js
$("#file_input").change(function (e) {

    var URL = window.webkitURL || window.URL;
    var url = URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]);
    img = new Image();      
    img.src = url;
    img.onload = function () {
        var canvas = new fabric.Canvas("c");

    ///
     fabric.Image.fromURL( img.src, function( img ) {

  // add filter
  img.filters.push(new fabric.Image.filters.Grayscale());

  // apply filters and re-render canvas when done
  img.applyFilters(canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));

  // add image onto canvas
  img.width = canvas.width;
  img.height = canvas.height;
  canvas.add(img);
});
    }

    ///
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.5.0/fabric.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input type="file" id="file_input"/>
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```